# Replace the first duplicated element in rows in with NA while remaining the rest duplicated

Tags: r

I find that rows in my dataframe often have the 1st element duplicated by another element in the same row. I want to replace this 1st element that is duplicated with NA and keep the other element.

My dataframe has many columns but let me demonstrate it with only 3 columns c1, c2 and c3 like this

```
c1 c2 c3
1  1  4
5  2  9
3  1  8
7  2  7
9  9  1
```

I want to get this

```
c1 c2 c3
NA 1  4
5  2  9
3  1  8
NA 2  7
NA 9  1
```

Could you help me, please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `apply`

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE) & 
              seq_along(x) == 1, NA)))
df1
#  c1 c2 c3
#1 NA  1  4
#2  5  2  9
#3  3  1  8
#4 NA  2  7
#5 NA  9  1
```

---

Or use a vectorized option with `rowSums`

```
df1[,1][rowSums(df1[,1] == df1[-1]) > 0] <- NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L), c2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 9L), c3 = c(4L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: When I used your code, it turns out that if the value in column c2 is duplicated, it replace this value to NA, too. I just want to replace the value in column c1 which is duplicated with NA and remain the rest of the dataframe. Could you help me with this once again, please?

Comment: @NguyenPhuongThaoNgan  I updated the post.  can you check

Comment: I'm so sorry that I accept your answer late. I started to use this website since this afternoon and I didn't know how to accept the answer. Thank you so much.